# Magnitude of the series over primes $p$ of exponential functions $\sum_{p} e^{-pt}$

Tags: number-theory

Is the magnitude of the series $\sum_{p} e^{-pt}$ summed over all primes $p$ with $t$ a positive real constant known?

Comment: What is t? Is it a constant?

Comment: @Szeto Hi, yes, $t$ is a positive real constant.

Comment: So it's a function of $t$ then?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp yes, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(t) = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} e^{-t p}
$$
and let $g(z)$ be the related 
$$
g(z) = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} z^p
$$
Clearly, we have the relation $g(e^{-t}) = f(t)$. One interesting note is that by the Fabry Gap Theorem, $g(z)$ has a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$, so $f(t)$ will have a natural boundary on the imaginary axis. Neither of these functions has a simple closed form in terms of any functions I have ever seen, though the Mellin transform of $f$ is relatively simple (see below).

For the asymptotics of $f(t)$, as $t$ goes to $\infty$, since $2$ is the smallest prime, we will certainly have
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} e^{2 t}f(t) = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{p \text{ prime}} e^{-t (p-2)} = 1 + \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{p > 2 \text{ prime}} e^{-t (p-2)} = 1
$$
giving us the asymptotic equivalence $f(t)  \sim e^{-2t}$. When $t$ approaches $0$, it's a lot more difficult. We can easily see that $$f(t) < \sum_{n\ge 2} e^{-t n} = \frac{e^{-2 t}}{1 - e^{-t}} \sim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac1t$$ 
We can actually do a little better than this, as we will show that asymptotically as $t$ approaches $0$, we have $f(t) \sim \frac1{t\log t}$. To do this, observe that the Mellin transform of $f$ is:
$$
\operatorname{M}[f](s) = \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} f(t) dt = \sum_p \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-t p} dt = \sum_p p^{-s} \Gamma(s) = P(s)\Gamma(s)
$$
where $P(s)$ is the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function), which is known to have a logarithmic singularity at $s = 1$. Indeed, assuming [RZH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), $P(s) + \log(s - 1)$ can be analytically extended below $\Re{s} = 1$ (in fact, this follows from the weaker assertion that the zeta function does not have zeroes with real part arbitrarily close to 1). Therefore, we must have that $f(t)$ has a singularity of the appropriate type at $t=0$ to make this happen, and one can easily see that $\frac1{t\log t}$ is the correct function, because
$$
\int_0^\alpha \frac{t^{s-1}}{t\log t} dt = \operatorname{Ei}((\log \alpha)(1-s)) = \log (1-s) + c - s + ...
$$ 
(where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary constant in $(0,1)$, and $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral))
Hence $f(t) - \frac1{t\log t}$ must have a singularity at $0$ such that 
$$
\int_0^\alpha t^{s-1} \left(f(t) - \frac1{t\log t}\right) dt
$$
is analytic on some region $(1-\epsilon , \infty)$. In particular, $\int_0^\alpha f(t) - \frac1{t\log t} dt$ converges, whence we conclude $f(t) \sim \frac1{t\log t}$ when $t \rightarrow 0$.

Without the assumption that the Riemann zeta function does not have zeroes with real part approaching $1$, the picture becomes a lot more complicated, and I don't know exactly what sort of singularity we ought to expect, but it would probably be just slightly above $\frac1{t\log t}$.

**Some other properties of f and g**

We immediately have:
$$
f^{(n)}(t) = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} (-p)^n e^{-tp}
$$
Interestingly, $g$ relates to the Goldbach conjecture:
$$
g(z)^2 = \sum_{n\ge 1} g_n z^n
$$
where $g_n$ is the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of two primes. According to the Goldbach conjecture, $g_{2n} > 0$ for $2n \ge 4$. This function has probably been studied at some point, but I couldn't find anything in Google.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a connection that You could spot by a glance between the asymptotics of $f(t)$ as $t\to 0$ and $\exp\left\{\sum_p p^{-x}\right\}$ as $p\to\infty$ for some $0<x<1$, or possibly, between $\lim_{t\to 0} \int f(t) t^{s-1}dt$ and $\exp\left\{\sum_p p^{-x}\right\}$, please? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect $f\sim \frac{1}{t\log t}$ as well. I'm still expecting an answer in a closed form... I'll mark Your post as an answer if no one chimes in with a closed form asymptotics, of course.

Comment: A closed form for the singularity at $0$ or a closed form for $f$?

Comment: Good idea to look at the Mellin transform, I'll see if there's anything I can do with that.

Comment: close form of just the singularity at $0$.

Comment: OK, using the Mellin transform idea I have proven it is $\frac{1}{t \log t}$. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: awesome, thanks!

Comment: I don't believe it can be pushed any further unconditionally either. I'll keep the question open for few more days. Please do chime in if a new idea springs in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be your original sum.

Let $F_N$ be the $N$th partial sum.

If one accepts that
$$p_n\approx n\ln n$$

then $$F-F_N\approx\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-tn}$$ which may have some linkage with the sophomore dream.

Comment: Hi. I was expecting a close solution, bounds, or asymptotic behavior as $t\to 0+$ and $t\to\infty$. By the way, the sum in your answer is $F_N$, not the difference. How would you sum it up as $N\to\infty$? And I don't understand the "sophomore dream" reference.Edit: just reading about it on Wikipedia :D Edit2: oh, greater than... Sorry, misread it. I'm still hoping for a more close-form answer.

Comment: I am really not sure I buy this $\approx$ sign here. What is true is that if $a_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} b_n$ and $a_n \geq 0$ with $\sum_n a_n$ divergent, then $$\sum_{n\geq N } a_n\operatorname*{\sim}_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n\geq N}b_n$$ **But** here you have $p_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} n\ln n$, and it is **not** true that $e^{-t p_n} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} e^{-t n\ln n}$. To conserve the equivalent when taking exponentials, you need to go to the $o(1)$ term in the asymptotics, not just the first term like here.